# Sign discrepancy between two different definitions of ricci curvature

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curvature

In my differential geometry course, the $(1,3)$-riemann curvature tensor $R$ is defined by
$$R(X,Y)Z:=\nabla_X\nabla_YZ-\nabla_Y\nabla_XZ-\nabla_{[X,Y]}Z$$
and the $(0,4)$-riemann curvature tensor Rm by
$$Rm(X,Y,\color{red}Z,\color{blue}W):=g(R(X,Y)\color{blue}W,\color{red}Z)$$
In coordinates $Rm_{ij\ell k}=g_{\ell m}R_{ijk}^m$. The symmetries are the following: $$Rm_{ijk\ell}=-Rm_{jik\ell}=-Rm_{ij\ell k}=Rm_{k\ell ij}$$
Then the Ricci tensor of a riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ is the symmetric $(0,2)$-tensor $\text{Rc}\in\Gamma(T^*M\otimes T^*M)$ ${\it defined}$ by:
$$\text{Rc}(X,Y)=\sum_{i=1}^nRm(X,e_i,Y,e_i)$$ where $\{e_i\}$ is an orthonormal basis of $T_pM$. It's coordinate representation is $Rc_{ik}=g^{j\ell}Rm_{ijk\ell}$. Then the notes states (without proving it) that $Rc(X,Y)$ is the trace of the map $Z\longrightarrow R(Z,X)Y$.

This implies that (using the symmetries):
$$\boxed{Rc_{ik}=g^{j\ell}Rm_{ijk\ell}=-g^{j\ell}Rm_{ij\ell k}=-R_{ijk}^j}$$

---

Wikipedia defines the tensor $R$ in the same way, while it defines the Ricci tensor $Rc(X,Y)$ directly as the trace of the map $Z\longrightarrow R(Z,X)Y$. Then it states that:
$$\boxed{Rc_{ab}=R^c_{acb}}$$

---

The question is: what's the source of the sign discrepancy between the two boxed formulas? Isn't it true the trace characterization of the Ricci tensor using the definitions in my notes? Or have I made some calculation mistakes in the first boxed formula?

Maybe it's a silly question, but I would be glad of any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The notation $R^c_{acb}$ is ambiguous: does it mean $g^{cd}R_{dacb}$, or $g^{cd}R_{adcb}$, or $g^{cd}R_{acdb}$, or $g^{cd}R_{acbd}$? In other words, which index position corresponds to the raised index $c$? The various choices differ by a sign. For that reason, it's important to maintain both the horizontal and vertical positions of indices. The [Wikipedia article on Ricci curvature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ricci_curvature) does exactly that: the equation you quoted actually appears there as
$$
\text{Ric}_{ab} = R^c{}_{bca} = R^c{}_{acb},
$$
showing that the raised index belongs in the first position.
On the other hand, your computation, if you keep track of horizontal index positions, yields
$$
Rc_{ik}=g^{j\ell}Rm_{ijk\ell}=-g^{j\ell}Rm_{ij\ell k}=-R_{ij}{}^j{}_{k}
$$
Using the symmetries of the curvature tensor, this can be rewritten as
$$
-R_{ij}{}^j{}_{k} =
-R^j{}_{kij} =
R^j{}_{kji},
$$
which matches the Wikipedia formula.